# Double out of range in java

Tags: java, double

while i'm making my own calculator i'm facing a problem in which my double data type converts my answer in an unknown format here is my sample code

```
class Myclass
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        Double d = 0.0000001 * 1;
        System.out.println("D = "+d);
   [1]}
}
```

[please check the image for the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ull4I.png)

how to resolve this kind of problems?

Comment: that's just scientific notation - an artifact of the display. It doesn't change the underlying value in your program

Comment: Are you trolling? There’s no error in your image. It’s scientific notation. More specifically, E-notation.

Comment: i know it's scientific, but i can't just wander the user by those numbers i need to change them to the form of powers

Comment: Please show text output *as text* - there's no point in having a screenshot just for text.

Comment: You may find [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) useful.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a problem .It is the output. `1e-7` refers to `1x(10^-7)`  or one multiplied by ten power minus seven .

Comment: yeah i know that but how could i show that to the users or else how can i convert my number to the power form

Comment: Use `System.out.printf`  with `%f` .

Comment: @dev: "yeah i know that" - so why did you write "my double data type converts my answer in an unknown format"?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Sir that is his justification for being  unclear about what to ask .

Comment: I didn't know what's that called in a programming term so only I wrote it down it was a mistake bro,  don't take it seriously.. @jon_skeet

Comment: @devjoshi: I suggest you spend more time on your questions in future. Put effort into being as clear as you can. Bear in mind that the purpose of the site is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1):

Like the others have said, that is just scientific notation. If, however, you want to get all those decimal places instead of scientific notation. You can use `System.out.printf("%f%n", d);` where the %f means a float (double in your case) and the %n just means a new line. 
Take a look at [the java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for more detail

Comment: Mrwayfarout it helped me but can I do the same with a text field